# how do I get the atd daemon log at commands?

Tags: cron, rsyslog

On HPUX all `at` jobs are logged in a `cron.log` file. Alas I cannot find similar on Ubuntu.

I see `cron` is logged to `syslog` and I can change `rsyslog` to log to a `cron.log`. But my attempts to log `at.*` jobs to the same file failed.

Not logging `at` jobs mean that there are no traces of scheduled commands.
This could be an easy way for fraud jobs and I regard this as a security flaw.

Is there an easy way to get all batch jobs logged without changing the whole system to secure Linux?

Comment: Did you solve yr prbm, or do you still need assistance ?

Comment: Problem still unsolved. I think the atd programmers need to do a better job